# Scheduling php script in phpMyAdmin 3.3.8.1

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have the following php script that I need to schedule to run in phpmyadmin. I am using a cron to run it but its not updating the table.  It is not giving me an error either so I am sure something is wrong with my php file.  Here is the code.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("xxxx", "xxxx", "xxxx") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("xxxx") or die(mysql_error());

$query = "update events 
INNER JOIN tblfeatureddj 
ON events.id_user = tblfeatureddj.id_user 
set trending ='2'";

?>
```

Comment: Are u sure the cron is set up properly. Most controlpanel require u start the location of your script from your home folder

Comment: Post the command for your cron. Also, stop using `mysql_` functions.

Comment: The cron is built into the network solutions control panel, its just picking a file to run and the frequency.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the network solutions control panel, but most cron jobs are command line commands -- you'll need to find out if it's expecting a command to execute or how the interface wants you to provide input. If I understand you correctly, there's no where for you to type anything and you just select the file from a dropdown menu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can indeed schedule events from within phpMyAdmin (provided you have the proper permissions, of course). From within your database, click the Events tab. From there, you can add a new event (and turn on the "Event scheduler status" button, if the scheduler is turned off). Something like this should do nicely for you:

[image: Event scheduler interface]

Comment: Although I don't think this feature existed in 3.3.8.1. You should really upgrade anyway, though, as that version is more than four years old at this point.