# Run php script every day

Tags: php, sql, phpmyadmin

Is there any way I could run a php script every day with phpmyadmin? I can't do it with the events because I need to send a mail to the user which I can't do with SQL.

Thank you

Comment: use chron job in phpmyadmin

Comment: 1.you can create a function to get data from db and send mail to them. 2.Now you can run this function with `cronjob` on your server. 3.add that function in `cronjob` and add time delay of 24 hour. 4.done

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I set a MySQL event schedule using phpMyAdmin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6622301/can-i-set-a-mysql-event-schedule-using-phpmyadmin)

Comment: in linux or windows?

Comment: You can set cron job to every day and perform your logic into it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can write your query and/or script in a function
then use the cronjob on the server to call this function every certain time
 so for example if you are using ssh 
do the following

```
$ crontab -e
```

this command will open the cronjob page to list all the cronjobs you have 
then enter the following line

```
0 1 * * *  path_to_your_function
```

then save and close

> 0 1 * * *
>   it means everyday at 1 o'clock the server will call the function that has the queries or the php script you wrote

you can customize the cronjob timing and test it [here](https://crontab.guru/)

i would also like to recommend you to check the answer on [Scheduling php script in phpMyAdmin 3.3.8.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22846392/scheduling-php-script-in-phpmyadmin-3-3-8-1)